# Returning a response from a pure JS AJAX call - POST

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

This is my PHP function to store some data:

```
case "start_question":

    $user_id = "123";
    $p_id = $_POST[""];
    $question_id = $_POST["question_Id"];
    $answer = $_POST["answer_String"];
    $counter = $_POST["counter"];
    $points = $_POST["answer_Points"];
    $user = new User($uid);
    $user ->end_question($p_id,$user_id,$question_id,$answer,$counter,$points);
    echo "Hello World";
    break;

}
```

And this is the JS Ajax Call:

```
function startQuestion(){

    var question_Id = questions_array[question_counter].question_Id;
    console.log("Start Question",question_Id);
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var params = 'question_Id=' + question_Id;
    ajax.open("POST", "ajax_controller.php?m=start_question", true);
    ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    ajax.send(params);
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
        console.log(response);
        var response = "";

        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 1) {
            response += "Status 1: Server connection established ! <br/>";
        } else if (xmlHttp.readyState == 2) {
            response += "Status 2: Request recieved ! <br/>";
        } else if (xmlHttp.readyState == 3) {
            response += "Status 3: Processing Request ! <br/>";

        } else if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
            if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {
                var text = xmlHttp.responseText;
                response += "Status 4: Processing Request ! <br/>";
                response += text;
            } else {
                alert("Something is wrong !");
            }
        }
    }
    //If an error occur during the ajax call.
    if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 404) {
        console.log("Error during AJAX call");
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is to log in the console the ''Hello World'' response back after PHP has finished processing the results.

PS: Actually I would like to fire a function with a parameter ''hello world'' but If I figure out how to get the response back it should be trivial to do this.

Comment: Question: Why not use jQuerys' ajax functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its basically just a typo probably from a copy/paste that you didnt completely check.

Your XMLHttpRequest() object is called `ajax` and not `xmlHttp` so you pick up the responsea and readyState from your ajax object and not xmlHttp.

Also you should move the `ajax.send(params);` to be run after you have told the XMLHttpRequest object what to do with the respose when it is received.

```
function startQuestion(){

    var question_Id = questions_array[question_counter].question_Id;
    console.log("Start Question",question_Id);
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var params = 'question_Id=' + question_Id;
    ajax.open("POST", "ajax_controller.php?m=start_question", true);
    ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
        console.log(response);
        var response = "";

        if (ajax.readyState == 1) {
            response += "Status 1: Server connection established ! <br/>";
        } else if (ajax.readyState == 2) {
            response += "Status 2: Request recieved ! <br/>";
        } else if (ajax.readyState == 3) {
            response += "Status 3: Processing Request ! <br/>";

        } else if (ajax.readyState == 4) {
            if (ajax.status == 200) {
                var text = ajax.responseText;
                response += "Status 4: Processing Request ! <br/>";
                response += text;
            } else {
                alert("Something is wrong !");
            }
        }
    }
    //If an error occur during the ajax call.
    if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 404) {
        console.log("Error during AJAX call");
    }


    ajax.send(params);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what the problem is...

`xmlHttp.readyState == 4` is fired when the request is complete, being when PHP is finished processing your request.

What if you just perform your action within the `xmlHttp.readyState == 4`?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your response text is stored into `xmlHttp.responseText`, so you can work into :

```
if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {
    console.log(xmlHttp.responseText);
    /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`xmlHttp` in your given code seems to be undefined. Try to replace it with your actual ajax object:

```
if (ajax.readyState == 1){ ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put `ajax.send(params);` after `ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {/*...*/}`;

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this right , you should put the console.log (response) where you actually receive the response i.e.

```
var text = xmlHttp.responseText;
                response += "Status 4: Processing Request ! <br/>";
                response += text;
                /**********************/
                console.log(response)
               /**********************/
```